# How to store and make use of session id in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, perl

I am trying to implement a shopping site. On clicking on Checkout button, i am trying to check whether user is already logged-in or not. IF yes want to show payment form to him , else login Form.

While he is providing correct info (Username and password), in login script i am trying to create a session.

```
// On providing correct username and password

use CGI::Session qw();
my $s = CGI::Session->new;
$s->param(User_id => 12);
my $id = $s->id; # e.g. '4cd29ac608405e4d0a463d153e64defd'
```

I want to make use of that session id.

My problem is how store the session id in HTML, and make use of that to display different forms based on this session id.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Devesh

Comment: The client (browser) needs to pass back to the web server, so it's usually stored in a cookie. It's by far the simplest method.

Comment: If you wanted it passed by to you as a CGI param, you'd need to generate a hidden field with the value and/or append in to the URLs in the pages you send to the client.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend authorisation based on id sent by hidden input field, as it can introduce safety issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from reading this page: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Cookie.html

CGI::Cookie object will allow you to store session id in browser's cookies.

This is example how to save and read cookies:

```
$cookie_sid = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'SID',-value=>$session_id);

print header(-cookie=>[$cookie_sid]);

# reading cookies
%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
$id = $cookies{'SID'}->value;
```